# A java program to print a multiplication table with a different condition

Tags: java

Write a complete Java program that will take an integer and print the a
multiplication table modulus the given integer. If the value is less than
2 or greater than 10, the program should complain and exit. Since all of
the numbers consist of only a single digit, it will not require much work
to get the columns to line-up. The first row and column should list the
numbers (0 . . . n − 1).
I tried my best in bellow code, but I think something is missing init as per above question. Please help in solving this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hw2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int number;
        number = input.nextInt();
        if(number<0)
        {
            number = (-1)*number;
        }
        if(number>=2&&number<=10)
        {
            for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(number+" "+"x "+i+" ="+(number * i));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter numbers from 2 to 10 only");
            System.exit(number);
        }
    }
}

output:

Enter a number: 
10
10 x 1 =10
10 x 2 =20
10 x 3 =30
10 x 4 =40
10 x 5 =50
10 x 6 =60
10 x 7 =70
10 x 8 =80
10 x 9 =90
10 x 10 =100
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the exact answer you need.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hw2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Accepting an Integer
        System.out.println("Enter a Integer:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = input.nextInt();
        if(N<2||N>10)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter integrs in range 2 to 10 only");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("    ");
            for(int i = 0; i<N;i++ ) {
                System.out.print("  "+i);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
            //printing multiplication table by modulus of integer
            for(int i = 0 ;i<N;i++) {
                // print left most column first
                System.out.print(i+"  |");
                for(int j=0;j<N;j++) {
                    System.out.print("  "+((i*j)%N));;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does it really help the OP, who is obviously learning how to program, to just give the complete solution without any explanation?

Comment: The OP did ask what the problem is in that code, not a code dump.